# Error in callback <function post_execute at 0x7fc092c7c6d0>

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, figure

I got an error message when I tried to save images.

I want to save images in their proper location with proper names. So I made a save.fig name with specific file locations and specific names and orders.
In the name, 'box' is box, 'hid' is name, 'j' is order.
While I made and save successful images, sudden number it stopped and showed below error messages.
Usually,

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

This error occurred when multiple data(ex, np.array) were put in the location for single data. But when I let print each variable in fig name, as you can see below, It shows only one value. Also, some other objects are working well(until end), some show the same error while working.

I don't know what is the problem and how can I fix it.
Could you help me?

```
box: 12 , name: 49889211, order: 154 (it worked)
box: 12 , name: 49889211, order: 155 (sudden stopped)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-a21bf9d7aa6b> in <module>()
    198 
    199 
--> 200         plt.savefig('/home/myname/location/output_'+str(box)+'/name_'+str(hid)+'_'+str(j)+'.png') #for saving images
    201         #plt.show() #for showing images
    202 


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Error in callback <function post_execute at 0x7fc092c7c6d0> (for post_execute):
```